# ALB host based routing without domain name

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, clearml

I'm trying to configure host based routing in AWS ALB for ClearML server using [this tutorial](https://allegro.ai/clearml/docs/docs/deploying_clearml/clearml_server_config.html#configuration-procedures).
However, I don't have a domain name. So can I only use alb's dns for this routing?

For example, I will have the address as app.***.ap-north-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com, api.***.ap-north-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team

As long as the respective `app...`, `api...` and `files...` names are redirected to the correct ports, there should be no issue.

Additionally, the new documentation link for the setup guide has changed to [this](https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/deploying_clearml/clearml_server_config#sub-domains-and-load-balancers)